# Adding health checks with AddHealthChecks().AddCheck() prevents calls to IHeathCheckPublisher.PublishChecks

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code, I see calls to `IHealthCheckPublisher.PublishAsync`:

```
await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
   .ConfigureLogging(loggerBuilder =>
   {
       loggerBuilder.AddConsole();
   })
   .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
       services.AddHealthChecks();
       services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, SimpleHealthCheckPublisher>();
   }).RunConsoleAsync();
```

and:

```
internal class SimpleHealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
    private readonly ILogger<SimpleHealthCheckPublisher> logger;

    public SimpleHealthCheckPublisher(ILogger<SimpleHealthCheckPublisher> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("HealthReport received: {Status}", report.Status);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I see the following output:

```
HealthReport received: Healthy
```

However, if I add a trvial health check, `IHealthCheckReport.PublishAsync` is never called:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck("test", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy("We're good"));
```

How do I add a health check but still get `IHealthCheckReport.PublishAsync` to be called?

Full repro available here:https://github.com/anvilcloud/HealthChecksRepro

**Update #1:**
This works by setting the `TargetFramework` to `net7.0`. Unsure why. Unfortunately, I need it to work for `net6.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the HealthChecks packages worked for me:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions" Version="6.0.14" />
```

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" Version="6.0.14" />
```